# Tally in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Say I have data of the following form

```
ID
1
2
2
2
3
4
4
4
```

How can I tally? So the result would be

```
n count
1  2
2  0
3  2
```

in SQL Server

Notice that n != ID. n is the number of distincs (1), doubles (2), triples (3). So this is different from previous questions. I want to group by count not by ID.

Comment: Have you tried a query  on a sub-query containing the count totals?

Comment: My query in practice is much more complicated than this. I don't mind doing a query of a sub-query, but if there is another way then I would be all ears.

Comment: I would attempt to use some of the sub-query suggestions in the answer sections (perhaps with RowNumber to accommodate 0 instances), but if it is more involved than it looks to be here, then cursors and/or UDFs may help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use an aggregation of aggregations:

```
select cnt, count(*)
from (select id, count(*) as cnt
      from t
      group by id
     ) t
group by cnt
order by cnt;
```

Note:  This does not return the `0` row.  If you really need that, you need a `left join`:

```
select v.cnt, count(t.id)
from (values (1), (2), (3)) v(cnt) left join
     (select id, count(*) as cnt
      from t
      group by id
     ) t
     on v.cnt = t.cnt
group by v.cnt
order by v.cnt;
```

Comment: I keep getting errors on line 6. This is because my data base has the form `[parent].[db].[table]`. I get a, `Incorrect syntax near '.'` error. How do I work around this?  This is referring to your `left join` block of code. The line that has `) t`

Comment: @Alex . .  There is nothing obviously wrong with that code.

Comment: sorry, I just realized what the problem is. This code works.

Comment: @Alex . . . It is rather odd that you accepted an answer that doesn't return the results you specify in your question, especially when another answer does so.

Answer (score 1):

You could use an inline table:

Step 1 would be to aggregate them to determine which number was a "single", "double", or "triple".

```
SELECT
  `ID`,
  COUNT(`ID`) AS `count`
FROM
  `nums`
GROUP BY
  `ID`;
```

Which gives you:

```
ID   | Count 
-------------
1    | 1
2    | 3
3    | 1
4    | 4
```

Then you take the count of each of those:

```
SELECT 
  `count` AS `n`,
  COUNT(`count`) AS `count`
FROM
  (
    SELECT
      `ID`,
      COUNT(`ID`) AS `count`
    FROM
      `nums`
    GROUP BY
      `ID`
    ) AS `counts`
GROUP BY
  `count`
ORDER BY
  `count`
```

Which gives you

```
 n   | Count 
-------------
1    | 2
3    | 2
```

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e5098f/5)

Comment: I would still like the row with 0 counts

Comment: It looks like @Gordon Linoff's answer addresses that already, and since the list (1..n) is not already used in this query, unless you have another reference table to use, you would need to generate the list statically.